# Prove $s_{n+q} > s_n$ when $ s_n = \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n})$ and $f(x)$ is strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

While I was doing some exercises about monotonic functions I thought about a proposition, but I don't know really well how to proceed to prove it, or maybe it could be even false :

> Take a strictly increasing, and bounded function $f(x)$ on the interval
> $[0,1]$, and define $\displaystyle s_n = \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n})$,
> then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ there exists a  $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_{n+q} > s_n$.

It seems really linked to integrability of monotonic functions but It doesn't seem to me that it is sufficient to prove this one. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have a couple of questions.

1. Any constant function will serve as a counterexample if you desire a strict inequality. Do you expect a monotone inequality?

2. Do you want $q$ for each $n$ or want $q$ applying for every $n$? Put differently, would you first give me an $n$ and then ask for $q$, or ask for $q$ that works for all $n$?

Comment: For the second question, instead , I want to prove existence of $q$ for each $n$

Comment: Sorry, with monotonically I meant strictly :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have clarified in the comment, I will assume strict monotonicity of the function. If you are seeking for such $q$ for each $n$, simply put $q=n$ :

$$s_{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{2n} f\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n
\frac{1}{2n}\left[ f\left(\frac{2i}{2n}\right) + f\left(\frac{2i+1}{2n}\right)\right]
$$
$$> \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2n} \left[ f\left( \frac{2i}{2n}\right)+f\left( \frac{2i}{2n}\right)\right] = s_n.
$$

This argument works equally for discontinuous functions.

Comment: oh man, thank you!! I was thinking about $2n$ right in this moment :D
!

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to use integrability of increasing functions. Defining $t_n = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac kn)$, we have :

$$s_n <\int_0^1 f(x) \ dx < t_n \implies 0 < \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx-s_n < \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{n}$$

Then $\{s_n\}$ converges to  $\int_0^1 f(x)$ when $n \to + \infty$ for squeeze theorem, so since $s_{n_1} < \int_0^1 f(x)$ for all $n_1$ there must exist a $n_2 > n_1$ so that $s_{n_2} > s_{n_1}$.